# esp and ebp registers behavior in function call

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a main function that calls another function. I have read in many places that the following happens when a function call takes place:

```
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
```

My aim is to find the top of the stack before and after the function call. 
The following is my main :

```
#include <stdio.h>
long *ebp;
int main(){
    asm("movl %ebp,ebp");
    printf("Top of stack before calling function 0x%08x",ebp);
    func();
    return 0;
}
long *ebp;
long *ebp;
void func(){
    asm("movl %esp,esp");
    asm("movl %ebp,ebp");
    printf("\n\n Top of stack after entering function 0x%08x",ebp);
    printf("\n\n Top of stack before entering function 0x%08x",ebp+2);
}
```

My question is, should the print statement in main give the same value as the second print statement in func, as both of them give the top of the stack before entering the function?

Comment: This code writes to the variable esp twice but doesn't print it. It writes to ebp once and prints ebp and ebp plus 2. I don't think the code actually illustrates your question. If you can fix that maybe I can answer it.

Comment: Yeah sorry!! I changed it now.

Comment: You are doing things wrong, but anyway, the value of esp will differ by at least 4 due to the return address placed on the stack. If you are interested in register values you should probably use a debugger and not try to mess with inline asm.

Comment: You still don't print esp in func. It would also be helpful if you could clarify what you expect.

Comment: Okay I had the whole question wrong. I hope this edit clarifies my doubt.

Comment: If I look past the glaring issues with relying on there being stackframes present, the inline assembly accessing global variables directly and other assorted issues - *If* there are no stack based variables present and all that was pushed on the stack was _EBP_ in `func`, then ESP before the call and EBP+(4*2) inside `func` should be the same value. That's making a lot of assumptions. Remove the stackframe prologue, add local variables to `func` or build with optimizations then the values likely won't be the same.

Comment: Yeah so how would I find the top of the stack before I entered the function? (From the func). Ebp would point to the current top of the stack,ie, stack of the func function. At this point how would I find the top of the stack before I called func?

Comment: Upon entering the function the `esp` is pointing to return address (if the "function" was "called" in ordinary way). What code you do in the function and how you adjust `esp`, or if you even set `ebp` is up to your code. That said, I'm not sure, why you include C source. In C the `esp` or `ebp` are platform/compiler/options specific, so there's no general answer, and you can't find "top" of something, what is implementation detail and may change with any further compilation after adding few further lines or changing optimization level, or upgrading compiler.

Comment: Since you say you're printing the top of stack, I'm not sure why you're printing ebp, since esp is the top of stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you are correct about the function prologue,

```
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
```

then the difference between esp before calling the function and esp within the function should be 8 bytes, not 2: 4 bytes for the return address and 4 bytes for the saved value of ebp.